# What's the right way to select and combine objects with LINQ?

Tags: .net, linq

Here's a situation I run into frequently: I've got Parent and Child objects, and the Child object has a Parent property.  I want to run a query that gets the child objects and joins each one to the correct parent object:

```
Dim db = New DataContextEx()

get the children, along with the corresponding parent
Dim Children = From x In db.ChildTable
                Join y In db.ParentTable
                On x.ParentId Equals y.Id
                Execute x.Parent = y       <-- pseudocode
                Select x
```

The pseudocode shows what I want to accomplish: to return the child object x but with the code after the (fake) Execute statement executed.  I can think of a lot of ways to accomplish the end goal, but they all have a lot more lines of code and/or creation of temporary objects or functions that I find inelegant.  (Note this is VB.NET syntax, but it's not a VB syntax question, since AFAIK C# would have the same problem.)

So what would be the cleanest way to do what I'm trying to do?

**Edit**: People have asked about what ORM I'm using, but this is really a plain vanilla LINQ question; I'm not trying to convert this into logic to be run on the server, I just want some syntactic sugar to run the code client side after the query has been run on the server.

Comment: What is x.Parent in your code if x and y are table records?

Comment: It may help if you stated which provider you are using. Linq-to-SQL, Linq-to-Entities, etc., and further if you might happen to be using EF Code First.

Comment: They're just strongly typed objects from my ORM, but really this would apply equally to Linq To Objects.

Comment: Not sure which ORM you are using but the thing you are trying to do is something I would implement via foreign key in db - then ORM (at least Entity Framework) will set the values properly automatically for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These suggestions, especially [@Paul's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8660002/349974), were very helpful, but my final version is different enough that I'm going to write it up as my own answer.

I implemented the following totally general extension function:

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function Apply(Of T)(ByVal Enumerable As IEnumerable(Of T), ByVal action As Action(Of T)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    For Each item In Enumerable
        action(item)
    Next

    Return Enumerable
End Function
```

This is the same as ForEach, except that it returns the incoming sequence, and I think the name **Apply** makes it clear that there are side effects.  Then I can write my query as:

```
Dim Children = (
            From x In db.ChildTable
            Join y In db.ParentTable
            On x.ParentId Equals y.Id
            ).
            Apply(Sub(item) item.x.Parent = item.y).
            Select(Function(item) item.x)
```

It would of course be better if there were a way to have custom query operators, so I wouldn't have to use the lambda syntax, but even so this seems very clean and reusable.  Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: To improve this answer, I'd suggest modifying `Apply` to operate on a single item.  Then, the syntax would be cleaner: `Select x.Apply(Sub(c) c.Parent = y)`  (It's a more generic version of @Paul's answer)

Comment: @ScottRippey: +1 for the good suggestion.  It does seem cleaner and takes away the side effects.  I'm going to try both ways and see which feels more natural in use.

Comment: @ScottRippey: I did this and decided to keep both Apply methods, since they both seem applicable in various situations.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 11):

You could use an anonymous type when projecting results. C# example:

```
var items = from x In db.ChildTable
            join y In db.ParentTable on x.ParentId equals y.Id
            select new { Child =x , Parent=y };
```

Then assign the parent properties.

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
    item.Child.Parent = item.Parent;
}

return items.Select(item => item.Child);
```

Also you may want to use some ORM solutions for this instead of rolling your own.

Comment: This produces an IEnumerable(Of <anonymous type>), not IEnumerable(Of Child), which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Ok I updated the code. You better use foreach loops when manipulating data

Comment: @JoshuaFrank - It appears that you're trying to introduce side effects (setting a property) into a LINQ query. LINQ (and functional programming in general) isn't designed to do that. Either create a new instance (Child or anonymous type) in Select or add a subsequent foreach.

Comment: I believe the loop is redundant in this scenario. All items are enumerated during the query execution - it can be optimized to do whole logic within that loop and avoid additional looping.

Comment: I agree with @Paul, and, mainly, the thing I'm trying to avoid is that many lines of code.

Comment: It is not a good idea to change the objects you are iterating on. Your queries in LINQ should not introduce any side-effects. If you are bothered by foreach loop you can create new Child objects in your select clause. You would have to transfer all data from your loop variable then set the parent property.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

Add a method to do your logic to Child class that returns `this` or `Me` in vb

```
class Child
{
    public Child GetWithAssignedParent(Parent y)
    {
        this.Parent = y;
        return this;
    }
}
```

use this method in your select query to do the logic and return the updated instances of Child class:

```
var children = from x In db.ChildTable
join y In db.ParentTable on x.ParentId equals y.Id
select x.GetWithAssignedParent(y);
```

or use Func<>

```
var children = from x in children
join y in parents on x.ParentId equals y.Id
select
   new Func<Child>(() =>
   {
      x.Parent = y;
      return x;
   }).Invoke();
```

Comment: +1 for the good suggestion, and I was doing this for a while, but it doesn't sit quite well with me because (1) it requires modifying the class to add a utility function for a situation that may only be useful in one place; and (2) in the place where it's called, it's not so obvious what that method does without drilling into it.

Comment: you could create extension method not to add extra code to the original class.. I am not familiar with your code - but probably you could come up with a proper method name that will be clear in your particular case.

Comment: or you could create utility method (static method) that will take parent and child as two parameters, assign parent to child's property and return updated child.

Comment: Perhaps an extension method called `SetParent`?  How does this look: `select x.SetParent(y);`

Comment: I've added inline Func<> version that doesn't require any new methods/extensions.

Comment: I really liked the idea of the inline `Func<>`, but it's pretty hard to read ... plus, it won't compile, because `x` and `y` are not actual variables, they're parts of the LINQ query ... you'd have to pass them as parameters to the delegate, which will make the code even HARDER to read.  It would look like `select new Func<Child, Parent, Child>((x,y)=> { ... })(x, y);`

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't compile for you. It works just great in a sample project. No need to pass `x` and `y` as parameters.

Comment: I can't get it to compile either, but I'm also not sure the readability is high enough to make this a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's probably the easiest solution:

```
var children = from x in db.ChildTable
               join y in db.ParentTable
               on x.ParentId equals y.Id
               // Assign the Parent to the Child:
               let parent = (x.Parent = y) // <-- Inline assignment (with a dummy variable "parent")
               select x;
```

Disclaimer:  this query has **inline assignment** and **modifies state** ... both of which are not considered "best practice".
However, it is very easy to read and understand, maintainable, and easily produces the correct results, so I'd argue it is a great solution.

Also, this will only work in C#, because VB.NET doesn't have inline-assignment.

Comment: Right, C# only, but IMO it's also the kind of code that shouldn't be written in C# either, because it flagrantly depends on something tricky; I wouldn't like to look at this a month from now and try to figure out what it's doing.

Comment: Agreed, but in this scenario, a simple comment `// Assign the Parent to the Child:` is more than enough to self-document the code.  
The other solutions (`foreach` loop, extension method) will definitely take more time to figure out, and require much more code to read through.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using LinqToObjects, use this code to assign Parents to the Children.

```
ILookup<int, Child> lookup = children.ToLookup(c => c.ParentId)

foreach(Parent p in parents)
{
  foreach(Child c in lookup[p.Id])
  {
    c.Parent = p;
  }
}
```

---

If you're using LinqToSql, use DataLoadOptions to load related records.

---

If you're using LinqToEntities, use .Include to load related records.

Comment: As I mentioned in my edit, I'm looking to solve this problem in Linq in general, not just for objects pulled from a db.

Comment: @Joshua Frank, As I mentioned in the first 50% of my answer, there's a simple way to modify objects which are not in a database.

Comment: Simple yes, but highly verbose, which is most of what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank "highly verbose"?  It's less verbose than the top-voted answer.

Comment: That one's too verbose also.  I'm not sure why it got so many votes.